# how to send request to server with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-mvc

I have a web application that is developed in jquery and spring mvc...all is working perfectly...but now I want to use React JS in my application...i want to create a form in react js and send ajax request to my spring mvc controller...I know how to do it with jquery but not with react js....kindly tell me a way to create a form and send a request to the spring mvc controler....
this is my controller method where I want to get request...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String Save(/*@Valid Users user, BindingResult result,*/HttpServletRequest request, Model model, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean reverseBeforeSave) {
   
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String firstName = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("last_name");
        System.out.println("save method");
        String[] roleNames = request.getParameterValues("roles");

        userService.saveUserandRoles(userName, password, firstName, lastName, roleNames);
        return "success";
        
    }
```

I went through different solutions in StackOverflow and have searched on google but I am not getting any proper result.

Answer (score 9):

Install axios

```
$ npm install axios
```

Import axios

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Example GET request

```
axios.get('https://api.example.com/')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Example POST request

```
var body = {
    firstName: 'testName',
    lastName: 'testLastName'
};

axios.post('https://api.example.com/', body)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to send XMLHttp Request to server from your react.js application. 
example:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://<server-url>/saveuser";
var params = "param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value";
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
http.send(params);
```

you can also use some beautiful libraries like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch), [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), [request](https://github.com/request/request) etc.

Comment: can you please add code for React js form...i don't know how to create form in react js...

Answer (score 3):

One of the later APIs usually used for communicating is **`fetch`**, that is also slowly becoming a browser standard.

### `fetch` API Doc

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

## `fetch` Usage

More at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json', { // optional fetch options
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // you may send any data, encoded as you wish. shall match content-type 
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        redirect: 'follow', // *manual, follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        // manipulate response object
        // check status @ response.status etc.
        return response.json(); // parses json
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        // use parseed result
        console.log(myJson);
    });
```

## Crossbrowser compatibility

Since browsers are not always uniform, you might consider using a polyfill, like `whatwg-fetch` @ https://github.com/github/fetch

## Form in react with fetch

```
import React from 'react';

export class ReactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
    };
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json', {
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      redirect: 'follow',
      referrer: 'no-referrer',
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          alert('Saved');
        } else {
          alert('Issues saving');
        }
        // you cannot parse your "success" response, since that is not a valid JSON
        // consider using valid JSON req/resp pairs.
        // return response.json();
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind()}>
        <input type="text" name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({username: e.target.value})}/>
        <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})}/>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" onChange={e => this.setState({first_name: e.target.value})}/>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" onChange={e => this.setState({last_name: e.target.value})}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add code for React js form...i don't know how to create form in react js...

Comment: @Ahmad : I've provided a react form example. But there is a bit more to it how you assemble your whole react app. But at least you have something to start with

Comment: ok, thanks...but please give me little bit more favor by telling me how to configure React JS in my application ? can you please tell me whole flow of configure React JS in my application then create form then send request to my controller....

Comment: I would suggest you starting off here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app . The answers are not meant to elaborate on how to set up and develop whole projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of this: axios,fetch or XMLHttpRequest. Project Axios has stoped from owner, fetch use more codes than axios and the last one is complex